# Disable log setting in Magento 1.9 then the URL admin page returns 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, 404-page

Hi I just disabled log setting in Magento 1.9 in admin dashboard:

**system-> configuration -> advanced -> developer -> log** settings and change `"enable log settings"` from `Yes to No`.

After that, the URL admin page returns **404 error page** then I cant login to admin dashboard anymore.

**Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advanced.**

Comment: Try to clean cache

Comment: Please try to revert from the database, flush Magento cache, check your log files and try to fix an error which coming in your log file.